# Session variables not persisting despite session_start(), values in session array dissappear

Tags: php, session, shopping-cart

Here is my code:

```
<?php session_start();

if(empty($_SESSION['name'])){
  $_SESSION['name'] = array();
  $_SESSION['price'] = array();
  $_SESSION['qty'] = array();
  $_SESSION['pic'] = array();
}

array_push($_SESSION['qty'], $_POST['qty']);
   
$details = explode("|", $_POST['item']);

array_push($_SESSION['name'], $details[0]);
array_push($_SESSION['price'], $details[1]);
array_push($_SESSION['pic'], $details[2]);

//I have tested the values inside the array here with 'echo', and they were all existing.

header("Location: ../p4-cartcopy.php");
```

This is the code that stores the session values, I have tested on this page that the values are indeed stored in side the session variable arrays.

However, when I go on a different page to test it with this code at top:

```
<?php session_start(); 
$namer = $_SESSION['name'][0];
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])) 
  echo $namer."hello";?>
```

I can only see hello, but not the actual name variable previously stored inside the session. It seems that the session variable is set, but the array is empty.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: try to use `var_dump($_SESSION);` to know what values stored in the session after the `array_push`

Comment: @GNassro This is what is printed: array(4) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(19) "Brown Sugar Yogourt" } ["price"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "9.99" } ["qty"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "2" } ["pic"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(21) "Pictures/snacks3.jpeg" } }

Comment: @GNassro It seems all the values I want are inside the session! However I am unable to retrieve these values from the other pages...

Comment: Solved it, had to add session start on top of php file..

Comment: but `session_start()` alredy exist in your two code ?

Comment: @GNassro you're right, I had deleted it after because it wasn't working, and then I re-added it afterwards. I'm not sure what actually fixed it